# Processing save() Function Saves Only Final Result

Tags: save, processing, processing.js

Here's my code...

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  surface.setResizable(true);

  smooth();

  dot = loadImage("1-DOT.png");
} 


void draw() {
  background(255);

  grid(dot, 5, .2);
}


void grid(PImage img, int dim, float scale) {

  int imgsize = floor(img.width * scale);    
  int canvassize;

  for (int i = 1; i <= dim; i++) {
    canvassize = dim * imgsize;
    surface.setSize(canvassize, canvassize);
    for (int x = 0; x < canvassize; x += imgsize) {
      for (int y = 0; y < canvassize; y += imgsize) {
        image(img, x, y, imgsize, imgsize);
      }
    }
    save("grid_" + str(i) + ".png");
  }    
}
```

The grid function takes an image file, a dimension parameter, and a scale. It creates square grids of sizes 0 to dim from image.

It should save each iteration of this grid as a file. But it doesn't. What I am left with once I run the code is (in this case), 5 identical 5x5 grids. I should have a 1x1 grid, a 2x2 grid and so on. I have also attempted to use saveFrame(), but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your dot image?

Comment: Sure. It is literally, at this time, a dot (with transparency)  http://imgur.com/MmlPkAu

Answer (score 0):

Majlik is correct that you aren't calculating your `canvassize` correctly. If you want it to be different each iteration of the loop, then you need to use `i` instead of `dim`.

But on top of that, it seems like a really bad idea to change the size of your `surface` in the middle of a call to `draw()`. That throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for me.

Instead, you'll probably have better luck if you create a `PGraphics` of whatever size you want and draw to that. Here's an example:

```java
void setup() {
  PImage dot = loadImage("dot.png");
  grid(dot, 5, .2);
  exit();
} 
void grid(PImage img, int dim, float scale) {

  int imgsize = floor(img.width * scale);    

  for (int i = 1; i <= dim; i++) {
    int canvassize = i * imgsize;
    PGraphics pg = createGraphics(canvassize, canvassize);
    pg.beginDraw();
    for (int x = 0; x < canvassize; x += imgsize) {
      for (int y = 0; y < canvassize; y += imgsize) {
        pg.image(img, x, y, imgsize, imgsize);
      }
    }
    pg.endDraw();
    pg.save("grid_" + str(i) + ".png");
  }
}
```

That creates these images:

[image]

Also, notice that I'm not calling this from the `draw()` function: your program would continuously create images, which is not necessary. Just create them once and then exit.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have mistake on calculating a `canvassize`. If I get your goal right you should use `i` instead of `dim`.

```java
canvassize = i * imgsize;                             // Corrected
```

Also it is easier to use `saveFrame` instead of `save`

```
saveFrame("grid_###.png");
```

But I tested in only with Java Mode (without `surface` methods).

Comment: This code generates an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yes this code was not tested for JS so I updated answer.